# Loop through elements with a given classname

Tags: jquery, dom

Using jquery, how can I iterate through all elements in a given class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```
$('.klass').each( function() {
    $(this)... // will be an instance of the element matching the class selector
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/